# li goes outside of div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I use this code below to show up right column on my wordpress blog. (List structure is generated by `wp_list_categories`.)

```
<div class="rcolumn">
    <li class="categories">Categories
        <ul>
            <li class="cat-item1">
                <a href="#">Cat1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="cat-item2">
                <a href="#">Cat2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

The thing is, that the contents of this column ignore div and are actually outside of it. Whole li categories goes outside of rcolumn.

```
.lcolumn {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}

.rcolumn {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding:0 5px;
}

.categories {
    margin-top:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    list-style:none;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I've just noticed - It's uncommon practice to use li elements outside of an ul, ol etc..

Comment: Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sCS26/, despite the invalid HTML.

Comment: Run your HTML through a validator and fix the errors.

Comment: Looks fine for me too. The `display:inline` should work fine. Do you have any other styles that you didn't show ? Like maybe a `float` ?

Comment: Changing the way of il/uls is impossible in this case since they are automatically generated. I need to adapt to it.

Comment: What do you mean by `outside of div` ? As you can see in the posted fiddle it is in the div :-s

Answer (score 0):

```
.rcolumn {
  float:left;
  display:inline;  
  padding:0 5px;
  overflow: hidden;   <-- try this?
}
```

Comment: *"Whole li categories goes outside of rcolumn"* -- so your solution is to hide them?

Comment: Technically that's true, but they won't be visible either, which I doubt is a good solution for the problem.

Comment: as specified, the problem is a little vague; drawing attention to the `overflow` property seemed appropriate.

Comment: overflow is not helping either. `li` is still parsed outside of `div`